# How to Style/Reduce Width of Material UI Alert Bar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

For now, I am not using any other styling or .css files on my page. The Alert's width extends to the whole page. I am trying this but it doesn't make any difference:

```js
function StatusMessage(){
    if (isRemoved){
      return (
      <Alert   style={{
        width:'50%',
      }}
      className='alerts' severity="success"> User Removed</Alert>
        )
      }
  }
```

Comment: Try to get rid of the `style` attribute: `<Alert width="50%" className...>`.

Comment: @RHShanks92 doesn't work ```Property 'width' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AlertProps'.ts(2322)```

Comment: Are you sure you can use that property on alerts? What about [this](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#1-specific-variation-for-a-one-time-situation)?

Comment: I knew we can't! That's why I was using styles. But since you suggested, I tried it once again. But the problem's solved now @RHShanks92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce, just threw into my React project and `style={{width:'50%'}}` works.

Ideas for debugging:

- remove redundant `className='alerts'`, that as well may mess it up when yourself or some library by accident defines CSS on such class.
- report within what container it resides: `block`, `flex-box` and others behave differently, although I tested on first two and both worked fine for me.
- Use browser debugger and report what CSS rules actually applied or were overruled to the element that may give more insights to help you.

Comment: it was probably the className messing up. It works now.